# I am not able to resolve the error :help me to solve the error Import "telegram.ext" could not be resolved

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm programming a bot for telegram and it's giving this error and I can't resolve it: "Import "telegram.ext" could not be resolved"
I tried several times to reinstall pip from telegram and it's not working!
I've tried several ways and I'm not able to resolve the error, I've checked everything and still the error persists

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pip uninstall telegram -y
pip uninstall python-telegram-bot -y
pip install -U python-telegram-bot
```

Then,

```
import telegram.ext
```

It should fix the problem